# Mozzarella turned out super rubbery

Tags: cheese-making, mozzarella

I recently tried making four batches of mozzarella, all of which turned out like a rubber band. The first three times around I used a one-hour recipe, but tried less rennet and a longer setting time for the curds the last time around. After that too turned out rubb(er)ish I was too dispirited to waste another gallon of milk.

Are there any classic pitfalls here? 
- too hot whey when stretching and folding
- overworking the curds when straining them
- overworking the melted curds
- too much citric acid or rennet

Does either of the above (or something else) jump out at anyone as the more obvious perpetrator? From reading online I feel like the consensus seems to be that usually rubbery mozz is caused by overworking it during stretching/folding, but I thought I was being so careful the last time around.

Greatly appreciate any pointers, thanks

Comment: Did you use Ultra High Temp pasteurized milk?  In the US, most common milk now is.  I have given up any hope of having nice, soft home made until I can find a source for farm fresh that will not charge me an arm and leg.  It seems that to get the cheese to come together with it automatically requires over-working and production of a latex like product at least for someone less experienced like myself.

Comment: Nope, low-temp pasteurised the first three, even unpasteurised (from a mate who's a dairy farmer) the last time around. But I think that's mainly about getting it to curdle at all anyway

Comment: Italian pizza bloke (colleague of a mate of mine) suggests I might not be using hot enough water during stretching. Will put on some gloves and crank up the temp next time